# Onlick on product images in Magento pops up wrong text

Tags: product, image, magento-1.9.2

Of recent, if anyone clicks on the image of my website, it pops up an onclick function with text **"dfsd"** I would love to change this or better still remove it. But, do not know where to find the file that has it magento(1.9.2) **Thank You**...image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head`, add the following to **Miscellaneous Scripts**:

```
window.alert = function() {
    debugger;
}
```

Flush cache, then load the product page using Chrome with Developer Tools open.

Click on the image and when the alert message appears, developer tools should show you when the alert message was called in javascript.

Post back with the file name and the line that Developer Tools tells you.

Answer (score 0):

Find that word by using `grep -R 'dfsd'` on your file system